# Symfony: embedRelation() controlling options for nesting multiple levels of relations

Tags: symfony1, embed, relationship, nested

I'm trying to set some conditional statements for nested embedRelation() instances, and can't find a way to get any kind of option through to the second embedRelation.

I've got a "Measure->Page->Question" table relationship, and I'd like to be able to choose whether or not to display the Question table. For example, say I have two "success" pages, page1Success.php and page2Success.php. On page1, I'd like to display "Measure->Page->Question", and on page2, I'd like to display "Measure->Page", but I need a way to pass an "option" to the PageForm.class.php file to make that kind of decision.  My actions.class.php file has something like this:

```
// actions.class.php
$this->form = new measureForm($measure, array('option'=>$option));
```

to pass an option to the "Page", but passing that option through "Page" into "Question" doesn't work.

My measureForm.class.php file has an embedRelation in it that is dependent on the "option":

```
// measureForm.class.php
if ($this->getOption('option') == "page_1") {
    $this->embedRelation('Page');
}
```

and this is what i'd *like* to do in my pageForm.class.php file:

```
// pageForm.class.php
if ($this->getOption('option') == "page_1") { // Or != "page_2", or whatever
    $this->embedRelation('Question');
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this. Any ideas?

Is there a preferred Symfony way of doing this type of operation, perhaps without embedRelation?

Thanks,
-Trevor

As requested, here's my schema.yml:

```
# schema.yml
Measure:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: measure
  columns:
    _kp_mid:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    description:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    frequency:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Page:
      local: _kp_mid
      foreign: _kf_mid
      type: many
Page:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: page
  columns:
    _kp_pid:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    _kf_mid:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    next:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    number:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    previous:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Measure:
      local: _kf_mid
      foreign: _kp_mid
      type: one
    Question:
      local: _kp_pid
      foreign: _kf_pid
      type: many
Question:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: question
  columns:
    _kp_qid:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    _kf_pid:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    text:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    type:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Page:
      local: _kf_pid
      foreign: _kp_pid
      type: one
```

Comment: Any chance you could put a sample schema in your question as I am a bit unclear at what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, no problem.  I also updated a lot of other information to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use embedForm() instead.  It ended up being some Doctrine_Query::create()->select()... and Doctrine::getTable commands followed by some foreach loops and embedForm statements.  So much for embedRelation!